# How to avoid writing the same tests multiple times when testing methods that call other methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I'm using C# although this question would probably apply to any language.

I have two methods A and B. 
A does some things and has 5 unit tests for it. 
B is basically the same as A, but does something else too. B calls A in its implementation.

How do I go about testing A and B? Copying and pasting A's tests seems like a lot of unnecessary repetition.
If A belonged to another class, we could just mock that class and verify that A was called, but seeing as A is part of the same class as B, we can't do that here.

What are the best practices in such a case?

Comment: Too little information. You need to show a good code example, showing exactly the relationships between the tests, A, and B. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Oliver has the right idea but I'll take a shot at explaining it, since it seems like there's still some confusion.

You start by writing a set of tests for Method A. Then when you go to write a set of tests for B, you should only be testing functionality in B. Meaning when you write your tests for B you should assume that A works perfectly, because you already tested it. And I wouldn't worry about mocking A in this case.

As a side note, I have a suspicion that A does not need to be public. Is it called from outside the class at all? If not, I would make it private and then write one set of tests, testing A through B.

Or if A is complex enough that you want to test it separately, then it probably warrants being broken out into its own helper class. Then you can mock it if you want as well.

If you could give some example code it would make it easier to help you too.

Answer (score 0):

So simply write only the tests for what you expect what method B should does. If it internally calls another private or public method or maybe achieves the same through internal code clones (or whatever) doesn't matter to you.

Only test one thing per test. If you have all your tests for A and all your tests for B and you make any breaking changes you'll get informed from your test environment.

Comment: So copy and paste the tests basically?

Comment: No. Just write the test what you expect to be done by calling B. The only exceptionn would be if B is a superset method of A (like CheckAndDelete() vs. Check()) then you have to *copy* the tests, otherwise simply check only what B as obviously done (derived from the method name)

Comment: Well yes. B is a superset of A as is written in the question.